# ¿Cómo desplazo bits hacia la derecha o izquierda?

Tags: sql-server

En MySQL existe este operador >> para desplazamiento a la derecha y este otro << para desplazamiento de bits a la izquierda, pero por lo que he visto indagando por internet, en SQL Server no tenemos esa suerte. ¿Alguien conoce alguna forma sencilla de poder hacer estas operaciones en SQL Server sin complicarse demasiado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puesto que las funciones `LEFT_SHIFT` y `RIGHT_SHIFT` asi como los operadores `<<` y `>>` solo funcionan a partir de la versión 2022, se puede hacer simplemente el cálculo matemático para mover los bits. Eso se refiere a multiplicar o dividir por la potencia de dos según como se quieran mover los bits.

Usando el ejemplo de la otra respuesta para comparar.

```
SELECT LEFT_SHIFT(12345, 5),
       12345 * POWER(2,5),

SELECT RIGHT_SHIFT(12345, 5),
       12345 / POWER(2,5);
```

Comment: Gracias Luis. Nunca decepcionas.

Answer (score 5):

Lo que estas buscando es RIGHT_SHIFT y LEFT_SHIFT.

Si quisiéramos mover el numero 12345, 5 bits a la izquierda, haríamos lo siguiente:

```
SELECT LEFT_SHIFT(12345, 5);
```

12345 en binario:  `0011 0000 0011 1001`

Después de moverlo 5 bits a la izquierda: `0110 0000 0111 0010 0000`

Dando como resultado en decimal: 395040

Mira la documentacion sobre manipulacion de bits en SQL Server: [Bit manipulation functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/bit-manipulation-functions-overview?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Pon algo de información en la respuesta. Para compartir un enlace mejor hazlo en un comentario.

Comment: Hola Patricio, esas funciones ya las había probado y no me las reconoció como funciones de transac-sql, me devolvía error.

Comment: Es importante mencionar que eso solo está disponible a partir de la versión 2022 y en ese caso también funcionan los operadores `<<` y `>>`.

Comment: Hola, te sugerimos revisar; [CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-)